# Program wont show all the lines in the report file

Tags: c, file, sorting, merge

i made a merge sort program but it that gives you the chance to sort by name(nombre option 3), id(dni option 1) or birth (fecha de nacimiento option 2)
The thing is that by id or by birth it works perfectly but when ti choose birth it doesnt show all the profiles originally sent:
The main file where it gets the information is this:

```
martincurzel 38937133 21/11/1996  
fernandocardozo 14588898 12/06/1970  
agustincastellano 24365211 30/05/1985  
juanpardo 35459896 02/10/1994  
joaquinazorda 28741536 04/06/1988  
martakim 26544153 04/03/1986  
juliagonzales 21458763 24/11/1974  
pedroquiroga 45668745 22/04/1994  
nicolasweinber 34125652 14/07/1988  
carlagarcia 40412478 03/04/1964  
paulafeiman 38746369 04/04/1983  
federicoazurraga 11445696 31/12/1989  
horaciofernandez 54769956 21/06/1985  
hernancrespo 22045369 22/10/1988  
mariagonzales 43568744 15/04/2002  
soladmiral 22457869 31/05/1979  
oliverutirriaga 40412536 23/07/2000  
paulapomez 12445687 14/01/1956  
walterdominguez 32877999 17/02/1978  
florenciahurni 33415222 22/11/1988  
oscardias 14784411 25/12/1977  
camilaoraidea 9547698 23/04/1935  
gabrielduarte 19963351 12/07/1969  
damianbogado 39478555 04/03/1999  
ulisesiralon 48745737 14/06/2003  
kevinpolman 39789412 02/07/1997  
ricardoreinas 14746966 04/05/1964  
joselopez 21458700 14/02/1975  
gustavocordera 47859634 11/07/1970
```

the code is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct
{
int d;
int m;
int a;
}tfecha;
int TAM = 15;

typedef struct
{
char nombre[20];
unsigned int dni;
tfecha nac;
}tperfil;

void sort(tperfil *a,int b)
{
int i, j,re;
tperfil temp;
if(b == 1)
{
    for (i=1; i<15; i++)
        for (j=0; j<15 - i; j++)
            if (a[j].dni > a[j+1].dni)
            {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
}
else if (b == 2)
{
    for (i=1; i<TAM; i++)
        for (j=0; j<15 - i; j++)
            if (a[j].nac.a > a[j+1].nac.a)
            {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
            else if(a[j].nac.a == a[j+1].nac.a)
            {
                if (a[j].nac.m > a[j+1].nac.m)
                {
                    temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j+1];
                    a[j+1] = temp;
                }
                else if(a[j].nac.m == a[j+1].nac.m)
                {
                    if(a[j].nac.d > a[j+1].nac.d)
                    {
                        temp = a[j];
                        a[j] = a[j+1];
                        a[j+1] = temp;
                    }
                }
            }
}
else if(b == 3)
{
    for (i=1; i<15; i++)
        for (j=0; j<15 - i; j++){
            re=strcmp(a[j].nombre, a[j+1].nombre);
            if (re>0)
            {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j+1];
                a[j+1] = temp;
            }
}}
}
void mergesort(char archivo[], char archivo1[], FILE *file, const int h)
{
int dia, dia1, mes, mes1, ano, ano1;
unsigned int dni, dni1;
char nombre[20], nombre1[20];
int re=0;
tperfil buffer[2];
FILE *arch;
FILE *arch1;
arch = fopen(archivo, "rt");
arch1 = fopen(archivo1, "rt");
fscanf(arch, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
strcpy(buffer[0].nombre, nombre);
buffer[0].dni=dni;
buffer[0].nac.d=dia;
buffer[0].nac.m=mes;
buffer[0].nac.a=ano;
fscanf(arch1, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre1, &dni1, &dia1, &mes1, &ano1);
strcpy(buffer[1].nombre, nombre1);
buffer[1].dni=dni1;
buffer[1].nac.d=dia1;
buffer[1].nac.m=mes1;
buffer[1].nac.a=ano1;
if(h==1)
{
    while((dia < 99) && (dia1 <= 99))
    {
        if(buffer[0].dni < buffer[1].dni)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[0].nombre, buffer[0].dni, buffer[0].nac.d, buffer[0].nac.m, buffer[0].nac.a);
            fscanf(arch, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
            strcpy(buffer[0].nombre, nombre);
            buffer[0].dni=dni;
            buffer[0].nac.d=dia;
            buffer[0].nac.m=mes;
            buffer[0].nac.a=ano;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[1].nombre, buffer[1].dni, buffer[1].nac.d, buffer[1].nac.m, buffer[1].nac.a);
            fscanf(arch1, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre1, &dni1, &dia1, &mes1, &ano1);
            strcpy(buffer[1].nombre, nombre1);
            buffer[1].dni=dni1;
            buffer[1].nac.d=dia1;
            buffer[1].nac.m=mes1;
            buffer[1].nac.a=ano1;
        }
    }
    fprintf(file, "zzzzzzzzzz 999999999 99/99/9999");
    fclose(arch);
    fclose(arch1);
    remove(archivo);
    remove(archivo1);
}
if (h==2){
        while((dia < 99) && (dia1 <= 99))
    {
        if(buffer[0].nac.a < buffer[1].nac.a)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[0].nombre, buffer[0].dni, buffer[0].nac.d, buffer[0].nac.m, buffer[0].nac.a);
            fscanf(arch, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
            strcpy(buffer[0].nombre, nombre);
            buffer[0].dni=dni;
            buffer[0].nac.d=dia;
            buffer[0].nac.m=mes;
            buffer[0].nac.a=ano;
        }
        else if (buffer[0].nac.a == buffer[1].nac.a){
            if(buffer[0].nac.m < buffer[1].nac.m){
                fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[0].nombre, buffer[0].dni, buffer[0].nac.d, buffer[0].nac.m, buffer[0].nac.a);
            fscanf(arch, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
            strcpy(buffer[0].nombre, nombre);
            buffer[0].dni=dni;
            buffer[0].nac.d=dia;
            buffer[0].nac.m=mes;
            buffer[0].nac.a=ano;
            }
            else if(buffer[0].nac.m == buffer[1].nac.m){
                if(buffer[0].nac.d < buffer[1].nac.d){
                    fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[0].nombre, buffer[0].dni, buffer[0].nac.d, buffer[0].nac.m, buffer[0].nac.a);
            fscanf(arch, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
            strcpy(buffer[0].nombre, nombre);
            buffer[0].dni=dni;
            buffer[0].nac.d=dia;
            buffer[0].nac.m=mes;
            buffer[0].nac.a=ano;
                }
                else{
                    fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[1].nombre, buffer[1].dni, buffer[1].nac.d, buffer[1].nac.m, buffer[1].nac.a);
            fscanf(arch1, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre1, &dni1, &dia1, &mes1, &ano1);
            strcpy(buffer[1].nombre, nombre1);
            buffer[1].dni=dni1;
            buffer[1].nac.d=dia1;
            buffer[1].nac.m=mes1;
            buffer[1].nac.a=ano1;
                }
            }
            else{
                fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[1].nombre, buffer[1].dni, buffer[1].nac.d, buffer[1].nac.m, buffer[1].nac.a);
            fscanf(arch1, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre1, &dni1, &dia1, &mes1, &ano1);
            strcpy(buffer[1].nombre, nombre1);
            buffer[1].dni=dni1;
            buffer[1].nac.d=dia1;
            buffer[1].nac.m=mes1;
            buffer[1].nac.a=ano1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", nombre1, dni1, dia1, mes1, ano1);
            fscanf(arch1, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre1, &dni1, &dia1, &mes1, &ano1);
            strcpy(buffer[1].nombre, nombre1);
            buffer[1].dni=dni1;
            buffer[1].nac.d=dia1;
            buffer[1].nac.m=mes1;
            buffer[1].nac.a=ano1;
        }
    }
    fprintf(file, "zzzzzzzzzz 999999999 99/99/9999");
    fclose(arch);
    fclose(arch1);
    remove(archivo);
    remove(archivo1);
}
if(h==3)
{
    while((dia < 99) && (dia1 <= 99))
    {
        re=strcmp(buffer[0].nombre , buffer[1].nombre);
        if(re<0)
        {
            fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[0].nombre, buffer[0].dni, buffer[0].nac.d, buffer[0].nac.m, buffer[0].nac.a);
            fscanf(arch, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
            strcpy(buffer[0].nombre, nombre);
            buffer[0].dni=dni;
            buffer[0].nac.d=dia;
            buffer[0].nac.m=mes;
            buffer[0].nac.a=ano;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(file, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", nombre1, dni1, dia1, mes1, ano1);
            fscanf(arch1, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre1, &dni1, &dia1, &mes1, &ano1);
            strcpy(buffer[1].nombre, nombre1);
            buffer[1].dni=dni1;
            buffer[1].nac.d=dia1;
            buffer[1].nac.m=mes1;
            buffer[1].nac.a=ano1;
        }
    }
    fprintf(file, "zzzzzzzzzz 999999999 99/99/9999");
    fclose(arch);
    fclose(arch1);
    remove(archivo);
    remove(archivo1);
}
}
 void ordenacion(char *a, int *g, int *h)
{
int i, j, dia, mes, ano;
int u = 0;
printf("Sort by DNI(opcion 1) or sort by birth (opcion 2), or by name (opcion 3) \n");
scanf("%i", h);
unsigned int dni;
char nombre[20];
tperfil buffer[16];
FILE *fichero;
fichero = fopen (a, "rt");
while (!feof(fichero))
{
    char str[10];
    strcpy(str, "Parte");
    char *num[] = {"01.txt","02.txt","03.txt","04.txt","05.txt","06.txt","07.txt","08.txt","09.txt","10.txt","11.txt","12.txt","13.txt","14.txt","15.txt"};
    strcat(str, num[u]);
    FILE *arch;
    arch = fopen (str, "a");
    for(i=0; i<TAM; i++)
    {
        if(!feof(fichero))
        {fscanf(fichero, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
        strcpy(buffer[i].nombre, nombre);
        buffer[i].dni=dni;
        buffer[i].nac.d=dia;
        buffer[i].nac.m=mes;
        buffer[i].nac.a=ano;}
        else
        {
            strcpy(buffer[i].nombre, "zzzzzzzzzz");
            buffer[i].dni=999999999;
            buffer[i].nac.d=99;
            buffer[i].nac.m=99;
            buffer[i].nac.a=9999;
        }
    }
    sort(buffer, *h);
    strcpy(buffer[15].nombre, "zzzzzzzzzz");
    buffer[15].dni=999999999;
    buffer[15].nac.d=99;
    buffer[15].nac.m=99;
    buffer[15].nac.a=9999;
    for (i=0; i<=TAM;i++){
    printf("%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[i].nombre, buffer[i].dni, buffer[i].nac.d, buffer[i].nac.m, buffer[i].nac.a);
    }
    for (i=0; i<=TAM; i++)
    fprintf(arch, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[i].nombre, buffer[i].dni, buffer[i].nac.d, buffer[i].nac.m, buffer[i].nac.a);
    fclose(arch);
    u++;
}
*g = u;
fclose(fichero);
}
void partes(char p[20][20], const int g)
{
int f;
char str[10];
char *num[] = {"999","Parte01.txt","Parte02.txt","Parte03.txt","Parte04.txt","Parte05.txt","Parte06.txt","Parte07.txt","Parte08.txt","Parte09.txt","Parte10.txt","Parte11.txt","Parte12.txt","Parte13.txt","Parte14.txt","Parte15.txt"};
//printf("%i", g);
for(f=1; f <= g; f++)
{
    strcpy(p[f],num[f]);
    //printf("%s", p[f]);
}
}
void merge(char p[20][20], int g, const int h, const int c)
{
while(g > 1)
{
    int i, j, dia, mes, ano;
    int div, res, k, l, o;
    unsigned int dni;
    char nombre[20];
    tperfil buffer[1];
    div = g / 2;
    res = g % 2;
    if(div != 0)
    {
        for(k=0 ; k<div; k++)
        {
            FILE *fichero;
            fichero = fopen("file.txt", "a");
            mergesort(p[(k*2)+1], p[(k*2)+2], fichero, h);
            fclose(fichero);
            rename("file.txt", p[k+1]);
        }
        if(res == 1)
        {
            FILE *arch;
            FILE *fichero1;
            arch = fopen (p[g], "r");
            fichero1 = fopen (p[div+1], "at");
            fscanf(arch,"%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
            strcpy(buffer[0].nombre, nombre);
            buffer[0].dni=dni;
            buffer[0].nac.d=dia;
            buffer[0].nac.m=mes;
            buffer[0].nac.a=ano;
            while(dia < 99)
            {
                fprintf(fichero1, "%s %u %i/%i/%i\n", buffer[0].nombre, buffer[0].dni, buffer[0].nac.d, buffer[0].nac.m, buffer[0].nac.a);
                fscanf(arch,"%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
                strcpy(buffer[0].nombre, nombre);
                buffer[0].dni=dni;
                buffer[0].nac.d=dia;
                buffer[0].nac.m=mes;
                buffer[0].nac.a=ano;
            }
            fprintf(fichero1, "zzzzzzzzzz 999999999 99/99/9999\n");
            fclose(arch);
            remove(p[g]);
            fclose(fichero1);
            g=div+res;
        }
        g=div+res;
    }
    else break;
}
}
int main()
{
int cantpart, cont, opcion;
char arch[20];
char part[20][20];
printf("Ingresar el nombre del archivo con los datos:\n");
scanf("%s", arch);
//muestra(arch);
ordenacion(arch, &cantpart, &opcion);
partes(part, cantpart);
merge(part, cantpart, opcion, cont);
rename("Parte01.txt", "Lista.txt");
return 0;
}
```

The main focus of all this lines of code has to be in the mergesort, because the initial sort works as shown in console by the printf: the end file called "Lista.txt" shows me the following:

```
agustincastellano 24365211 30/5/1985
camilaoraidea 9547698 23/4/1935
carlagarcia 40412478 3/4/1964
carlosfigueroa 50478731 14/6/2004
damianbogado 39478555 4/3/1999
facundokumis 50478741 14/5/2004
federicoazurraga 11445696 31/12/1989
fernandocardozo 14588898 12/6/1970
florenciahurni 33415222 22/11/1988
francolomero 22417444 24/11/1989
gabrielduarte 19963351 12/7/1969
gustavocordera 47859634 11/7/1970
horaciofernandez 54769956 21/6/1985
joaquinazorda 28741536 4/6/1988
joselopez 21458700 14/2/1975
juanpardo 35459896 2/10/1994
juliagonzales 21458763 24/11/1974
kevinpolman 39789412 2/7/1997
lucianochavez 15478855 25/12/1992
mariagonzales 43568744 15/4/2002
martakim 26544153 4/3/1986
martincurzel 38937133 21/11/1996
nicolasweinber 34125652 14/7/1988
oliverutirriaga 40412536 23/7/2000
oscardias 14784411 25/12/1977
paulafeiman 38746369 4/4/1983
paulapomez 12445687 14/1/1956
pedroquiroga 45668745 22/4/1994
zzzzzzzzzz 999999999 99/99/9999
```

There are some missing 4 profiles or tperfiles from the original .txt file
if i run the exact same program but instead of option 3(sort by name) i choose 1 or 2 it works perfectly.

Comment: Minor: About every place code has `&nombre` should be replaced with `nombre`.

Comment: Code is having trouble, yet code lacks checking the return value from `fscanf()` in many places.  Robust code checks  that.  Example  `if (5 != fscanf(arch, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano)) Print_ErrorAndQuit();`

Comment: Example `fscanf(fichero, "%s %u %i/%i/%i", &nombre, &dni, &dia, &mes, &ano);
        strcpy(buffer[i].nombre, nombre);` can be UB as code does not know if `fscanf()` succeeded.

Comment: `char str[10];
    strcpy(str, "Parte");
    char *num[] = { "01.txt", ...
    strcat(str, num[u]);` is certainly bad - buffer overflow.

Comment: Rarely is `while (!feof(fichero)) {` correctly used.  Check return value of input functions instead.